# How to divide tableview to sections and give headlines

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview in my app.
I want to divide my cells into sections and give headlines.

Below I attach the picture (animals, birds headlines):

[image]

How do I do that in dynamic prototype cells?

My section data:

```
   var sectionsData = [
       "header", 
       "description", 
       "diagnoses", 
       "perscription", 
       "notes", 
       "addFaxHeadline",
       "addFax", 
       "addEmailHeadline",
       "addEmails",
       "givePermissionHeadline", 
       "select answer"
   ]
```

Here is my cell at row function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   

        print ("indexPath: ", indexPath)
        print ("indexPath: ", indexPath[0])
        print ("-------")

        if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "header") {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "description") {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerInfoCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "diagnoses") {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diagnosisCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "perscription") {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "perscriptionCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "notes") {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addFaxHeadline") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addFaxCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addFax") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailNameCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addEmailHeadline") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addEmailCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addEmails") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailNameCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "givePermissionHeadline") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "permisionCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell

        } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "select answer") {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectAnswerCell", for: indexPath)

            return cell   

        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addFaxCell", for: indexPath)

        // <<<< ???

        return cell

    }
```

and my numbers in row per section function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        if (sectionsData[section] == "header") {
            print ("returning 1 ?")
            return 1
        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "description") {
            return 1

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "diagnoses") {

            //return visitSummary.diagnoses.count
            return 2

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "perscription") {
            //return visitSummary.prescriptions.count
            return 2

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "notes") {
            return 1

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "addFaxHeadline") {
            return 1

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "addFax") {
            return faxAdded.count

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "addEmailHeadline") {
            return 1

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "addEmails") {
            return emailsAdded.count

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "givePermissionHeadline") {
            return 1

        } else if (sectionsData[section] == "select answer") {
            return 1

        } else {
            return 0
        }

        return 0
    }
```

and my number of sections:

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        print ("sectionsData.count: ", sectionsData.count)
        return sectionsData.count
    }
```

All of the tutorials I find is for one section and I have a very amount of sections to show.

How would I divide it and give them headlines?

Comment: You should use `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath[0]`. I would also recommend to use an `enum` for section types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clean up your code first:

```
enum Section: Int, CaseIterable {
   case header = 0, description, diagnoses, prescription, notes, addFaxHeadline,  addFax, addEmailHeadline, addEmails, givePermissionHeadline, selectAnswer
}

var sectionData: [Section] = [
   .header,
   .description,
   .diagnoses
   ...
]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionsData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sectionData[sectionIndex]

    switch section {
       case .header:
          return 1
       case .description:
          return 1
       // ... 
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section = sectionData[sectionIndex]

    switch section {
       case .header:
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath)

          return cell
      // ... etc
    }
}
```

Now, we can return section title just using a `String`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> String? {
    let section = sectionData[sectionIndex]

    switch section {
       case .header:
          return "Header title"
       case .description:
          return "Description title"
       default:
          return nil
    }
}
```

Another option is to use [tableView(*:viewForHeaderInSection:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) and [tableView(:heightForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    view.addSubview(label)
    // setup constraints accordingly
    // setup title of the label
    return view
}
```

You can also use a custom reusable header which would be registered and dequeued in the same way cells are dequeued.

Comment: i'm not sure i can change it to enum, becouse i'm building that string array from another function, it's just hard coded here in the eample. can i build up an enum from code in 1 line ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog You should definitely use an enum instead of the string constants. However, I have updated the code to better match your use case.

Comment: with help your answer some suggestions from xcode, I solved my problem. Upvoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var sectionsData = [
           "header", 
           "description", 
           "diagnoses", 
           "prescription", 
           "notes", 
           "addFaxHeadline",
           "addFax", 
           "addEmailHeadline",
           "addEmails",
           "givePermissionHeadline", 
           "select answer"
       ] // Your Array

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? //*Data Source method for header title*
    {
        // Safe cast
        if let sectionArray = sectionsData as? [String]
        {
            return sectionArray[section]
        }

        // A fail safe
        return "No Header"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I see. You are misunderstanding how these methods work. They are called for every cell in every section.

So, if you return 4 in `numberOfSections`, the method `numberOfRowsInSection` will be called 4 times, and `sectionIndex` (now called `section` in latest versions) will have the current section (0 to 3 in our example).

Therefore, if you want to call the second section "Birds" and let all the others `nil`, your code will look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 1 {
        return "Birds"
    }
    // Otherwise
    return nil
}
```

Same thing for how many rows each section will have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        // 1 row for the first section
        return 1
    } else if section == 1 {
        // 3 rows for the second section
        return 3
    }
    // 2 rows for every other section
    return 2
}
```

And, finally, what cell will be used in each indexPath:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Figure out which row and section you are talking about
    let row = indexPath.row
    let section = indexPath.section

    // Now you know where you are in the TableView, create the corresponding cell according to your project
    // Start by dequeueing a custom cell using the identifier and forcing the cell to become your custom cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellID) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Do aditional setup to this cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "This is cell \(row) in section \(section)"

    // Return the cell when you are ready
    return cell
}
```

Remember Sulthan's suggestion to create an enum for your sections.